# phpmyadmin not loading on web server

Tags: mysql, web, phpmyadmin, load-time

phpMyAdmin does not want to load on the server. All other web apps (Piwik, RoundCube, etc) are loading fine on the same web server. All webapps are talking to the same MySQL server.

DB Server has load times of 0.99, 0.92, 0.56 (dual core cpu).

Web Server has load times of 0.00, 0.08, 0.10.

Comment: Have you take a look at your web server logs? Maybe an already in use port? Post some logs

Comment: What do you mean "not loading" ? an error message? a blank page?